# Transforming shredded cheese into chunk cheese

Tags: cheese

I am at an event where I need to serve cubed chunk cheese, but I only have shredded mozzarella.  Is there a simple way to melt mozzarella into chunks?  Any idea would help.

Comment: I've never tried it, but I'd be inclined to warm it up 'til it's soft (possibly in salted hot water, like when shaping it originally), work out the air, let it solidify in a slab, then cut it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a good solution: simply shape the mozzarella into smooth balls.  No melting even necessary!  At this point, I could have chopped them into cubes, but I left them as spheres.

Comment: Did you have to heat it?  I know that you typically put the mozzarella curds into hot water to soften up so that you can make it into balls.

Comment: Nope, didn't even need to heat them; just molded them like dough.

Answer (score 2):

Normally when you have smaller cheeses you use a cheese press to mash them together. Make 1 round of cheese. Only thing I could think of would be to see Felx. Our local blacsmith & have one made. As a specialty item. Kind of like a long handled garlic press with out the holes in it. Think along those lines. Something cube shaped you can mash the cheese together in.

Comment: In a similar vein to the garlic press-like thing, you might also be able to put it a disk in the bottom of a ricer and make a wheel (then cut it into cubes)

Answer (score 1):

There is no way, neither simple nor difficult. You can only create a block of cheese during production. Once you shred it, there is no way back.

You can in principle make processed cheese which is meltable and shapeable to a point, but it doesn't have the mouthfeel and taste of chunk cheese either. You have probably eaten it as these edges packed in foil which can be sperad on bread, for example from La vache qui rit.